# How to get the daily report using google adwords api?

Tags: api, google-ads-api

i'm starting with api google adwords here is my code :

```
$reportQuery = 'SELECT CampaignId,CampaignName, '
        . 'Impressions, Clicks, Cost FROM CAMPAIGN_PERFORMANCE_REPORT DATE 20151119 ';
       // . 'WHERE Status IN [Campagne mise en veille, PAUSED] DURING ' . $dateRange;
  // Set additional options.
  $options = array('version' => ADWORDS_VERSION);
 ReportUtils::DownloadReportWithAwql($reportQuery, $filePath, $user,
      $reportFormat, $options);
  $dataArray =file($filePath);
```

It works fine with 'During last_7_days' , but for daily stats it fails i tried 'Date today' and 'Date 20151119' but it doesn't work.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is the question?
What is $dateRange in your case?

Anyways, try:

```
SELECT CampaignId,CampaignName,Impressions,Clicks,Cost
FROM CAMPAIGN_PERFORMANCE_REPORT
DURING 20151119,20151119; //or: DURING TODAY
```

see docs: https://developers.google.com/adwords/api/docs/guides/awql

EDIT:
if you want a daily report you have to include the DATE column/attribute in the select clause and a valid timespan in the during clause

Comment: the question is how to get the report of today , i 've already tried TODAY but it doesn't work , it returns nothing.

Comment: Performance report data only really stabilises at 4am in the accounts timezone, so you're generally restricted to only being able to reliably pull yesterdays data

Comment: @lloydpick  thanks for the explaination , that's why it doesn't return me any data.

Comment: if I include the DATE column in the select clause, There is no "row" node response xml. But When I get report without "DATE", rows getting in xml.